# Is it possible to create and use a templated structure in DocBook 5?

Tags: html, xml, docbook-5

I'm using DocBook 5. Is it possible to create a template (let's call it 'mytable') with certain structures like:

```
<informaltable>
    <tgroup cols="1">
        <tbody>
            <row>
                <entry>
                    <inlinemediaobject>
                        <imageobject>
                            <imagedata fileref="{path_variable}"/>
                        </imageobject>
                    </inlinemediaobject>
                </entry>
            </row>
        </tbody>
    </tgroup>
</informaltable>
```

and reuse 'mytable' and also pass a variable to the template? So conceptually I can do:

```
mytable("path/to/file/1")
mytable("path/to/file/2")
mytable("path/to/file/3")
```

and so on, each of which expands to an 'informaltable' element.

Comment: XSLT is a perfect match for this.

Comment: Please, refine, how you form the initial DocBook document and at what step you want to fill the values by an automation? There are several possibilities but certain usecase is fully depend on your exact conditions.